# Embeding angular12 app in angularjs component

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular12

I have custom application written in angularjs. I would like to migrate some components to angular 12. There is no need to share data between these two apps (except cookie auth and backend apis).

How to embed angular 12 app inside div hosted by angularjs?
Are any long term problems with this?
If not, then maybe there are other web frameworks more suited for doing so?

Comment: You cannot embed an Angular app, but you can use [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) to create web components that you can then use anywhere, including in your AngularJS app.

Comment: Aviav P., it seems like a good answer for me (:

Comment: Ye, please post it as answer so people may upvote!